# Remove item from array if item value contains searched string character

Tags: php, arrays, substring, filtering, array-filter

I have an array built from the URL of a webpage.

If an item in that array contains the `?` symbol (The question mark symbol) then I want to remove that item from the array.

```
$array = ['news', 'artical', '?mailchimp=1'];
```

How could I do this? I've seen many examples where the searched string is the whole value, but not where it's just a single character or just part of the value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
function myFilter($string) {
  return strpos($string, '?') === false;
}

$newArray = array_filter($array, 'myFilter');
```

Answer (score 12):

```
foreach($array as $key => $one) {
    if(strpos($one, '?') !== false)
        unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're using >= PHP 5.3, use a closure.

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
   return strstr($value, '?') === false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP8, you can make calls of `str_contain()` inside `array_filter()` and invert its boolean return value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WHjep))

```
$array = ['news', 'artical', '?mailchimp=1'];

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($v) => !str_contains($v, '?')
    )
);
```

The above will keep the original keys, so if you need to guarantee that your result array is indexed, just call `array_values()`.