# Remove element from array if contains some string/symbol

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have an array containing some words and I want to remove the words that contain either a . (fullstop) or ; (semicolon) or some other symbols. I have read the solution on [ [Remove item from array if item value contains searched string character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993168/remove-item-from-array-if-item-value-contains-searched-string-character) ] but this doesn't seem to answer my problem.

What can I add to this code to remove also the words containing the other symbols other than semicolon?

```
function myFilter($string) {
  return strpos($string, ';') === false;
}

$newArray = array_filter($array, 'myFilter');
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the array your using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match` function:

```
function myFilter($string) {
    return !preg_match("/[,.]/", $string);
}
```

`[,.]` - character class which can be extended with any other symbols

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
// $array is your initial array
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $item){
    if ((strpos($item, ';') > 0)||(strpos($item, '.') > 0))
        continue;
    $newArray[] = $item;
}

// Words with ; or . should be filtered out in newArray
print_r($newArray);
```